# using an ssh server's tunneling capabilities as a web proxy

Tags: ssh, proxy, tunnel, ssh-tunnel

With SSH you create a tunnel for a host at a time. With the tools available this is usually a manual process. So if you wanted to do SSH tunneling for, for example, google.com, you'd have to maybe create an entry in your hosts file for google.com to map to 127.0.0.1 an then create an SSH tunnel on 127.0.0.1 to forward port 80 / 443 traffic to google.com.

Of course, using that approach you can't really do multiple websites at once and as such it's not really a good approach for tunneling all web traffic through an SSH server.

Are there any better approaches?

Comment: using socks proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is:

```
ssh user@hostname -D 9999
```

This will open an Socks proxy on your local machine, on port 9999. Then, configure your browser to use Socks v5 proxy, pointing to localhost, port 9999.